# How to delete object with Id in Realm or Primary Key?

Tags: react-native, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-list, realm-database

I have below object :

obj1 = [{ id = 1, name = "abc"}, {id=2, name="pqr"}, {id=3, name="xyz"}]

I need to delete an object with id=2 where id is Primary Key too.
Below method using to delete the object

```
 const collection = RealmDB.realm
      .objects("StudentName")
      .filtered(`id= $0`, '65');
    RealmDB.realm.write(() => {
      RealmDB.realm.delete(collection);
    });
```

But it is not working with id object can anyone please suggest better way to do this ?

But still that object is there so may I know what is wrong here.

Comment: It looks like you have a main object with a list of objects; are you trying to remove an object from the main objects list or totally remove the object completely?

Comment: yes trying to remove object from main objects list.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const id = 1;
realm.write(()=>{
   realm.delete(realm.objectForPrimaryKey('Baby',id));
})
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Hello resolved an issue by following query with no error

```
const collection = RealmDB.realm
          .objects('StudentName')
          .filtered('id= $0', `65`);
        RealmDB.realm.write(() => {
          RealmDB.realm.delete(collection);
```

Thank you

Comment: You don't need to filter for an object that has a primary key. It can be [directly read](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/react-native/examples/read-and-write-data/#read-operations); like this `const student = realm.objectForPrimaryKey("StudentName", $0);`

Comment: what is $0 and what about if wanted to filter for 65 id

Comment: Hmmm `$0` is from your code -> `.filtered('id= $0', `65`);` and is typically a placeholder. Either way - that's the code you need, just use `65` if that's the primary key value of the object you want to update.